# Register CredentialsProvider in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, authentication

I have a library and an android app using this library. I want to separate them into 2 different `repositories` in `git`. I am trying to use sub modules and add the library as a dependency after reading the following:

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies

However, I get the following error in `Android studio`: 
    ERROR: Cause: https://gitlab.com/blabla.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

Obviously, I need credentials to access the repository, but
how do I register `CredentialProviders` to make it work? Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use services like jitpack to share your library